# What chemicals or modifications are need for a biological creature to be able to develop as natural/organic suicide bomb?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry, natural-defenses

So in my world there’s a creature as big as a common rodent or as big as a rabbit in size. They live in packs, usually burrowed, but occasionally come to surface to get food. The alpha male is tasked with protecting the pack, which he does by exploding himself near the predator and hopefully injuring/killing the predator from the flying body bits or distracting this predator with the flying bits of his meat giving the pack time to run away. The force generated is something like a grenade.

All of the land predators don’t know the meaning of fear — think of a honey badger — so just trying to scare them won’t work, and generally the land predator is fine with this since they get free meal and develop thicker or harder skin or armor but they still need to hurry to eat that meat before it’s stolen by a flying predator or other predator, hence they can’t keep on chasing on this prey, and a flying predator can’t hunt this thing because they will just explode when carried, which is dangerous while flying, so they prefer to wait until this creature explodes to steal the meat.

And the base of my question in Chemistry.SE (which I just found out is gone, so I can’t remember properly what it said or copy-paste it, so bear with me if I make a mistake; I am not knowledgeable about chemistry) there’s no restriction for animal to not develop any explosive chemical component or chemistry naturally inside their body, stuff like that.

So I want to know what explosive chemical or gunpowder a biological animal could naturally develop, and what kind of organs would be needed to not endanger the creature themselves, before or outside of exploding.

- exploding due to just common gas like oxygen, water, fat/oil or ballooning like extreme pufferfish is out of the question, because that’s too plain and boring; I want it to be explode as fast as a grenade; ignite and explode, no need for them to enlarge first before the rupture.
- and I want to base it off of explosive chemicals or gunpowder materials.
- the explosive chemical or gunpowder should be waterproof and fatproof or moistureproof since the creature has blood and i want it to be able to explode even when bleeding either internally or externally.
- all of the pack members must have this ability, not just the alpha male, with each having different explosive strength, depending on their size, the alpha male being the biggest.
- they rarely get a chance to experience old age before dying but when they do, they just go yolo and suicide charge on any animal outside of their pack, even specifically targeting a predator den to kill an infant.
- they can still explode, even when the creature is unconscious or losing their brain, so that ambush tactics won’t work on them.
- not easy to explode from small shaking or impact or hit or bump since the creature do a lot of humping for reproduction purpose.
- not flammable or create flame and not easily combust or explode from general/common body temperature heat or small heat (but this can be exception if theres no chemical that can match my requirement)
- I haven’t thought of their diet yet since I think their diet will related to their explosive chemical or gunpowder development or process, but generally I think they probably won’t be carnivorous, but I am not going to exclude it if that’s the only option to get this explosive chemical.

Feel free to edit my grammar and tag to the appropriate one since I am not sure which tag is better for my question.

Comment: No editor should have to deal with that many corrections; if English isn’t your first language please feed your post through a better translator than GT and if it is then please take more time to edit.

Comment: @Fivesideddice - ummm... maybe editing is not a thing that fits everybody?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi its not like im forcing him to edit anyway. but overall i do appreciate his grammar edit though.

Comment: @LiJun  - that's the spirit

Comment: eliminating avenues of exploration as "too boring" is not generally conducive to good answers

Comment: @jdunlop so? its still eliminating stuff i dont want, and i also need element of the rule of coolness. rather than generating good answer seems more like it generating easy answer for answerer and gain point, in my opinion.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi — while I do appreciate that I didn’t have to edit it, basic grammar is a thing that fits everybody

Comment: @Fivesideddice basic *English* grammar may not be a thing that _easily_ fits everybody. Personally, I grade the ideas and useful content as more valuable than the correct form of expression, but then that's a personal choice (I'd love to see everybody else sharing this choice, but I'm not **that** naive to think it _will_ happen).

Comment: @Fivesideddice i never learn grammar though as my profile has say it enough, i dont even know what grammar is until it become meme or when people get mad in internet just from that, but i can understand or read english well, besides im not here to learn english anyway, nor this site seems to be specifically that kind of thing, and its not like i dont try to make it readable as best as i can.

Answer (score 3):

- The [bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle) uses  hydroquinone and hydrogen peroxide - which are mixed in a vestibule which drains outside; [see it in action on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Pib9qT-pccI?t=107). Make the vestibule exclusively internal and you have a steam bomb.
- Sorry, I can't find the specific compounds the [ant nest beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_nest_beetle) is using
- [Colobopsis explodens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colobopsis_explodens) doesn't use chemical explosions as such, they just "burst at the seams" so to speak (strain their body until they burst) and smother the attacker with a toxic goo (a popsci article [Exploding Ants Kill Foes, and Themselves, with a Blast of Toxic Goo](https://www.livescience.com/62354-exploding-ants-new-species.html)). Since this is purely mechanical, use whatever "toxic goo" you find available.